# Binding Label and Value to ComboBox Winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, null

I have this code

```
Public Sub FillCategoryCombobox(ByVal categoryList As List(Of tblCategory), ByVal LvName As ComboBox)
    LvName.Items.Clear()
    Dim itemValue = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
    For Each category As tblCategory In categoryList
        itemValue.Add(category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName)
    Next category
    LvName.DataSource = New BindingSource(itemValue, Nothing)
    LvName.DisplayMember = "Value"
    LvName.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub
```

I receive an error on

```
LvName.DataSource = New BindingSource(itemValue, Nothing)
```

Value cannot be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a dictionary to a datasource by using the ToList() method of the dictionary.

**Edit**

Some code:

```
LvName.DataSource = itemValue.ToList()
LvName.DisplayMember = "Value"
LvName.ValueMember = "Key"
```

Answer (score 1):

Never ever tried to bind a dictionary to a control's datasource or bindingsource.
Maybe that's not possible.
Why don't you use your categoryList as a DataSource (for the BindingSource or directly)

```
combo1.DataSource = categoryList
combo1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName"
combo1.ValueMember = "CategoryID"
```

or if you need to maintain the position:

```
dim bs as new BindingSource(categoryList, nothing)
combo1.DataSource = bs
combo1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName"
combo1.ValueMember = "CategoryID"
```

or create a `List(of category)` instead of a Dictionary.

btw. a full stack trace is always helpfull.

Comment: You can bind a dictionary to a datasource by using the ToList() method of the dictionary, but in this case he might as well just use the list he sends in.

Comment: My category list contains other properties and I just need the ID and the name value @Tony I will try that out

Comment: @Tony Kindly post your answer in separate post , your suggestion works

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the BindingSource? If not you can set the ComboBox DataSource to your list directly. And instead of using a dictionary you can use something simpler like a KeyValuePair.
Can you try the following:

```
KeyValuePair[] pairs = new KeyValuePair[0];
ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
box.DisplayMember = "Value";
box.ValueMember = "Key";
box.DataSource = pairs;
```